# How to reliably count preceding rows in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, counting

I would like to know how to count preceding number of rows of a given row, in a given order by clause, in MySQL.
Also the rows may be inserted randomly, so auto_increment is unreliable.

```
MyAgenda - List

ID   FROM                  TO
32   2017-09-26 12:35:00   2017-09-26 13:35:00
33   2017-10-10 12:35:00   2017-10-10 13:35:00
32   2017-10-17 12:35:00   2017-10-17 13:35:00
32   2017-10-24 12:35:00   2017-10-24 13:35:00
```

Like in this case, The rows are sorted by the "From" column, but apparently row 34 is inserted before row 36, but after sorting 36 is above 34, and if another row 37 is inserted it maybe above or below any row, or even at the top. So how can I reliably count the preceding number of rows above a given row, in a given order by clause?

Tried the subquery method but it is O(n^2) and will be painfully slow when the number of rows is large.

Comment: Next time please don't post images, but text instead. I've changed this for you this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This counts records before record #36:

```
select count(*)
from mytable
where from_date < (select from_date from mytable where id = 36);
```

Comment: So there's no faster method?

Comment: No. How should this be possible? Based on one record you must find all previous records. The only means to speed this up is an index on the field in question (here the from_date column).

Answer (score 0):

First I would suggest not to sort by one column only
try this

```
ORDER BY From, ID
```

about your question, not sure if i understood the question correctly but in that case this script may help

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM your_table
WHERE From > @From
ORDER BY From, ID
```

Comment: That's SQL Server / MS Access syntax, and that doesn't return the number of preceding rows...